# Attaching the Token to Outgoing Http Requests but I got page not found

Tags: flutter, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to flutter
when I am Adding     Token to Outgoing Http Requests but I got page not found.
you can see that I amde Try catch block It shows error and I also print Http  status code

It also print 404
what is the solution for it

```
Future<void> fetchandSetProduct() async {
var url = Uri.https('cakejaffna-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com',
    '/cakelist.json?auth=$authToken');

try {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  print(" ");
  print(url);
  print(response.statusCode);

  final extractData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  if (extractData == null) {
    return;
  }
  final List<Cake> loadedProduct = [];
  print(extractData);
  extractData.forEach((cakeId, cakeData) {
    loadedProduct.add(Cake(
        id: cakeId,
        imageUrl: cakeData['imageUrl'],
        title: cakeData['title'],
        hotelName: cakeData['hotelName'],
        rating: cakeData['rating'],
        ratecount: cakeData['ratecount'],
        amount: cakeData['amount'],
        details: cakeData['details'],
        categories: cakeData['categories'] as List<dynamic>));
  });
  print("karan");
  print(loadedProduct[0].imageUrl);
  _cakeList = loadedProduct;
  notifyListeners();
} catch (error) {
  print(error);
  print("rellay error");
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: When I try to access the same URL (`https://cakejaffna-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json`) I get `{
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}`, which seems correct.

Comment: yaa I get token but I couldnt fetch the data.   var url = Uri.https('cakejaffna-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com',
    '/cakelist.json?auth=$authToken');  this url is not found and status code shows 404

Comment: Ah, so the database exists? Could it be that there's no `cakelist` node in there?

Comment: here , that fetchAndSetProduct method fails but I dont know why it occurs?  Is it any problem in token ? But I have cake List

Comment: and please see my output image

Answer (score 0):

Url format should change like this

```
final url = Uri.https('cakejaffna-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com',
    '/cakelist.json', {'auth': '$authToken'});
```